# .htaccess doesn't take slash as valid character

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to make this rewrite work in my local server (OS X Mavericks with Apache) and it doesn't seem to work WHEN AND ONLY WHEN a forward slash is included in the condition:

```
RewriteRule ^procedures/new$ procedure.php [L,QSA]
```

This should rewrite `http://www.example.com/procedures/new` to render `http://www.example.com/procedure.php`, but returns 404 instead.

If I replace the forward slash with any other character, it works just fine:

```
RewriteRule ^procedures-new$ procedure.php [L,QSA]
```

This rewrites `http://www.example.com/procedures-new` correctly as it should.

It seems like mod_rewrite is not accepting the forward slashes as inputs. Any ideas on this?

Entire file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  Options +MultiViews
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteBase /

  RewriteRule ^procedures/new$ procedure.php [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Do you have a `.htaccess` in `/procedures/` folder also?

Comment: No, /procedures/ is not a folder, i just use it for rewriting, maybe apache is looking for the folder instead? This doesn't happen in any other server I work with...

Comment: What else is in your /.htaccess file? If you have a standard Wordpress etc. .htaccess in there, it could be doing all sorts of things to the URL. Did you add this line to an existing .htaccess? If so, where? Is it after RewriteEngine On and before other rewrites? The *L* flag is unnecessary if there is no RewriteCond in action, and *QSA* is unnecessary because it's done automatically _unless_ you hard code a Query String.

Comment: @MartíGascó: If you can answer all these question: Q1. Is this the only .htaccess or do you have another? Q2. Is this the only code in this .htaccess? If you have some other code then please post it in question? Q3. What is location of above .htaccess?

Comment: This is the only .htaccess file, which is located at the root of the domain, with this content:
(edited original question with the content)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as a shot in the dark, try turning off Multiviews. If the 404 is being generated by apache, this probably isn't the problem, but if it's being generated by procedure.php, maybe it doesn't like PATH_INFO?

```
Options -Multiviews
```

Comment: It worked! I found out when I saw /procedures/ was redirecting to procedures.php even if I deleted my .htaccess, and I removed that behaviour with -Multiviews. My original issue was resolved at the same time. Thank you!